# Android Studio error emn las activity.xml

Tags: android

He cambiado de ordenador y por lo tanto todas mis programas de app de Androiid Studio los he exportado.

Parece que todo funciona bien pero en algunas activiyty.xml en la pantalla de Design (donde se ve la pantalla visualmente) me sale una llave inglesa y no puedo verlo.

¿Como lo soluciono?.

Grcias.

Comment: Lo más probable es que te falte alguna librería en el gradle, tipo implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0', o implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'... sin ver el código del xml en cuestión es difícil de saber. Ponlo en la pregunta y así será más fácil encontrar el error.

Answer (score 0):

Esrte es un error que en encontrado en todos los que no funcionan:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:47)
at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:693)
at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getType(BridgeTypedArray.java:1024)
at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getType(BridgeTypedArray.java:809)
at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getValue(BridgeTypedArray.java:778)
at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.peekValue(BridgeTypedArray.java:847)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5951)
at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:697)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:99)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView.<init>(MockView.java:55)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView.<init>(MockView.java:51)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView.<init>(MockView.java:47)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:324)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:354)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:431)
at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:141)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:710)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$6(RenderTask.java:865)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$2.run(RenderExecutor.kt:174)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Answer (score 0):

Este es un error que me ha salido en las que no funcionan:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:47)
at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:693)
at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getType(BridgeTypedArray.java:1024)
at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getType(BridgeTypedArray.java:809)
at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getValue(BridgeTypedArray.java:778)
at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.peekValue(BridgeTypedArray.java:847)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5951)
at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:697)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:99)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView.<init>(MockView.java:55)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView.<init>(MockView.java:51)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView.<init>(MockView.java:47)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:324)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:354)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:431)
at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:141)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:710)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$6(RenderTask.java:865)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$2.run(RenderExecutor.kt:174)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema radica en que tengo esto:

```
android:autofillHints=""
```

en los EditText

Pero no se porque quitando eso me funciona.

Comment: Curioso error. Puede ser porque el autofillHints comenzó a ser utilizado para las versiones 26 y superiores. Igual si tu versión del SDK es para una versión anterior, por eso no te funcionaba

Comment: Si le pones android:autofillHints=" " con el espacio en blanco funciona.